# Пагинация (Карусель) ответов бота aiogram

Tags: python, парсер, aiogram, pagination

Пишу тг бота на aiogram  для подбора фильма по критериям.
использую api tmdb. для сбора критериев использую машину состояний и полученые ответы передаю непосредственно в парсер.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Вывод ответов выглядит из череды сообщений. Каким образом я могу сгруппировать вывод цикла в одно сообщение с возможностью "листать карусель" ?
заранее благодарен за помощь!

вот часть кода для вывода информации

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.year)
async def process_year(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['year'] = message.text

        # For "typing" message in top console
        await bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, ChatActions.TYPING)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        await bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            md.text(
                md.text('Genre is: ', md.bold(data['genre'])),
                md.text('Minimum Vote Average:', md.code(data['voteaverage'])),
                md.text('Minimum Year:', data['year']),
                sep='\n',
            ),
            parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN,
        )

        try:
            genre = data['genre']
            voteaverege = data['voteaverage']
            year = data['year']
            api_version = 3
            api_base_url = f'https://api.themoviedb.org/{api_version}'
            endpoint_path = f'/discover/movie'
            endpoint = f'{api_base_url}{endpoint_path}?api_key={api_key}&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&vote_count.gte=500&with_genres={genre}&vote_average.gte={voteaverege}&primary_release_year={year}'
            r = requests.get(endpoint)
            data = r.json()
            for info in data['results']:
                id = info['id']
                genre_ids = info['genre_ids']
                original_name = info['original_title']
                original_language = info['original_language']
                overview = info['overview']
                vote_average = info['vote_average']
                vote_count = info['vote_count']
                release_date = info['release_date']
                popularity = info['popularity']
                poster_path = info['poster_path']

                # For "typing" message in top console
                await bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, ChatActions.TYPING)
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                await message.reply(
                    f' Movie: {original_name}\n Release date: {release_date}\n Genre id: {genre_ids}\n'
                    f' Original languare {original_language}\n Overwiew: {overview}\n Voteaverage: {vote_average}\n '
                    f' Vote count: {vote_count}\n Popularity: {popularity}\n Genre id: {genre_ids}\n Movie_id: {id}\n'
                    f' Poster path: https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original{poster_path}\n'
                    f'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
                # Trailer Buttons
                buttons = [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Trailer YouTube',
                                        url=f'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=+{original_name}+ trailer'),
                           types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="More Info", url=f'https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/{id}')]
                keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                keyboard.add(*buttons)
                await message.answer(text='More Actions', reply_markup=keyboard)

                    # await message.reply(text='BUTTONSTEXT', reply_markup=random_movie_buttons())
        except:
            await message.reply('\U00002620 Check Your Enter! \U00002620')

    await state.finish()
```

Comment: Тег пайтон добавь

Comment: Как вариант, сделать просто две инлайн кнопки "Next" "Prev", при нажатии на которые берутся, сохраненные заранее в машину состояний (FSM), данные и дальше  просто редактировать сообщение меняя в нем текст, не?   
Тоесть вы сначала данные с каждого цикла записываете в массик/кортеж, а потом всё это сохранить в state.update_data(DATA), после вывести данные первого результата как текст и прикрепить под ним две кнопки, которые меняют страницу (тоже записанную в стейт) и относительно её передвигаются по массиву с результатом (который опять же в стейте).